# No login required but still I see Session Expired Response in JMeter

Tags: javascript, arrays, selenium, session, jmeter

I am automating load tests using Jmeter, I have very simple page where I'm putting data into input fields and buttons clicks. 
I see following response data:

```
function handleBack() { var programGroup = document.getElementById('programGroupName').value; if(programGroup == 'SE') { var url = $('#fundraiserPageURL').val();; var index = url.lastIndexOf('/'); if (index > 0) { newurl = url.substring(0, index); } var action = newurl + "/decodeCheckOutDetails.action"; encodeCheckoutFRHttpSession(action, 'backFormIdFR'); } }       
    Visit LLS.ORG   
    0  
  VISIT LLS.ORG
  Sorry! the session expired, please try again.
```

Comment: It happens only on load or even with 1 user? What's your server?

Comment: Yeah, see this screenshot https://screencast.com/t/ObCDMVnu1iE

Comment: It looks that you simulates checkout and buying items, maybe you are using old orders Ids and you need to add post processor for request for get current id. need more info about the requests

Comment: Okay, I am adding test plan with all the information for your review, please check this attached video https://screencast.com/t/MSEWWyEZ

Comment: You need to know/find out which parameter value need to be taken from request A and used in next request

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to upgrade to latest JMeter version ([JMeter 3.3](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-3.3) as of now) as looking into i.e. [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) GUI it appears you're sitting on the outdated version. Or at least make sure you use the following settings in order to comply with the [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265):

- Implementation: `HC4CookieHandler`
- Policy: `standard`

along with `HttpClient4` implementation in the [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults).

---

Also double check you performed **correlation** of all dynamic values using suitable [JMeter PostProcessors](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors).